# group by months and then group results by user id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I need to count employ's salary which depends on the number of rows added per months (with a unique `picture_id`, so if the same picture ID appears twice it counts only one time) - so as I understand I need to group by both `picture_id` and by months.

It works perfectly fine if I do it separately i.e.

```
group by MONTH(TimeAdded)
```

or

```
GROUP BY picture_id
```

Here is the code

```
$data_qqq = mysql_query("SELECT MONTHNAME(TimeAdded), COUNT(MONTH(TimeAdded)) FROM Picture_Tag WHERE UserID = $user_id GROUP BY MONTH(TimeAdded)");
```

but this counts number of entries added each months even if there are 20 rows with the same `picture_id`.

Now if I try

```
$data_qqq = mysql_query("SELECT MONTHNAME(TimeAdded), COUNT(MONTH(TimeAdded)) FROM Picture_Tag WHERE UserID = $user_id GROUP BY MONTH(TimeAdded),**picture_id**");
```

I get a very strange messed up results...

Any idea how to count number of rows added each months with the unique `picture_id`?

Comment: It would help to see some dummy data, to get an impression of what the table looks like

Answer (score 0):

Without samples it can be difficult to visualize the data, but if you wish to count the number of unique picture_id's each month then use the `COUNT(DISTINCT picture_id)`. But also note when grouping by "month" you most probably also need to group by year otherwise the result could be badly skewed. (Alternatively use a where clause to only the select the single year you are interested in.)

Try this:

```
SELECT
   YEAR(TimeAdded)
 , MONTH(TimeAdded)
 , COUNT(DISTINCT picture_id)
FROM Picture_Tag
WHERE UserID = $USER_ID
GROUP BY
   YEAR(TimeAdded)
 , MONTH(TimeAdded)
```